# No routes matched location "/" in React

Tags: reactjs, routes

```
Hello, I am new to React ,this problem acccured and never found the solution or expalanation
```

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
// import Product from "./pages/Product";
import Home from "./pages/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="Home" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`the error was : No routes matched location "/"  . and this is the comopnent tree : [components tree]`your text`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBKUb.png)

I coudn't find an explanation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the root URL ("/") is often the starting point and the default route.
However if you don't want to have a ("/") route in your application you can use Redirect to redirect to /home from /

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/home" />} />
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the path of your root route inside browser router to “/“.

Right now you have a single route defined, which matches only the url-path “home“.

Answer (score 0):

please take a reference in below code

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />

        {/* Redirect unmatched routes to '/not-found' */}
        <Redirect to="/not-found" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <div>Home Page</div>;
}

function About() {
  return <div>About Page</div>;
}

export default App;
```